# How to get EPOCH date time format in angular 6?

Tags: node.js, angular, angular6

I want my date, time to be in EPOCH format in angular. Can anyone help me how to get date in EPOCH format?

```
let UCCdateformated = formatDate(today, 'yyyy-MM-dd', 'en-US', '+0530');
console.log("UCCdateformated  ",UCCdateformated);
```

Comment: Have you looked at the [DatePipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do that in Vanilla JavaScript, without relying on any of Angular's pipes.

To get the current moment's epoch time,

```
const epochNow = (new Date).getTime();
console.log(epochNow);
```

To get the epoch time of a particular hour (eg. today's date at 12am),

```
const epochToday = (new Date).setHours(0,0,0,0).getTime();
console.log(epochToday);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `datePipe` as follows. But angular dates don't come with locales, so you can pass some placeholder like `====` and later replace it with `locale` as

```
  formatDate(date = Date.now(), format=`yyyy-MM-dd ==== z`, locale='en-US'){
    let dateStr = this.datePipe.transform(date, format);
    let dateStrWithLocale = dateStr.replace('====', locale);
    alert(dateStrWithLocale);
  }
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g9uav6?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 1):

Using angular 11

```
const epochNow = (new Date).getTime();
console.log(epochNow); get the time in epoch assuming that is in milliseconds
```

If you want set a default time:

**Example:**

```
const epochNow = (new Date).setHours(0,0,0,0);
console.log(epochNow); get the time 12am with your time zone
```

Now if any of these properties is set, you can change the result[image]